# How to programmaticaly bind props to a dynamic component in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am making a generic system that instantiates dynamic components with custom props.

I would like to pass reactive props to these components.

App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="setData">Set data</button>
    <input v-model="text" style="margin-bottom: 15px" />
    <component
      :is="data != null ? data.component : {}"
      v-bind="data != null ? data.props : {}"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomComponent from "./CustomComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    CustomComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      text: "Custom text",
      data: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setData() {
      this.data = {
        component: CustomComponent,
        props: {
          // I would like this to be reactive without adding :title="text" on my <component>
          title: this.text,
        },
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

CustomComponent.vue :

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["title"],
};
</script>

<template>
  <p>{{ title }}</p>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

Here's the codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-props-on-component-r8fdym

I tried using `:title="text"` on the `<component>` and it is working but I would like to avoid this because I can have multiple components with different props to pass.

Is there a way to reproduce the result of `:title="text"` but programmaticaly ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is what v-bind is for. It's unclear what you mean by reactive. this.data.title won't react to this.text changes, in case that's your intention

Comment: I want `title` in `CustomComponent.vue` to change when `text` in `App.vue` is updated.

I want `this.data.props.title` be some kind of reference instead of a value.

As if it was directly binded with `:title`.

Comment: The way it should be done depends on how it's supposed to work in practice. I assume this example isn't your real case and it differs in some way. As with any reactive dependencies, needs to be done either with a watcher or computed

Comment: Yeah you are right, I wanted to avoid a computed but I guess it will be the only answer.
Thank you !